# Skip indexing empty string with custom analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, analyzer, stop-words, inverted-index

This is my custom analyzer

```
"analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
    "just_lowercase": { "type": "custom", "tokenizer": "keyword", "filter": ["lowercase"] }
  }
}
```

<s>I would like to ignore all the fields that are null or empty strings. I understood that this is the default behaviour of the standard analyzer; how can I reproduce the behaviour in my custom analyzer?</s>

**Updated question:** I would like this behaviour: the Query Exists on a field (analyzed by `just_lowercase`) must return no document with null values or empty string values. Is it possible?

**Update number 2:** Here is my new idea: I tried to use a custom analyzer with a stopword filter to skip indexing the empty string, but it doesn't work. After these setting with *Elastic Search 2.2* I was expecting to find NO document, instead I find both.

Here you can find my analyzer, documents and query. It works with *Sense* (Chrome Plugin for ES) http://pastebin.com/QyRvtdzV

Comment: What do you mean ignore?

Comment: I mean that the Query Exists on that field must return no document with null values or empty string values

Comment: And what makes you think that the analyzer is changing the way the empty fields are indexed? Do you have a test case for this?

Comment: I read somewhere about this behaviour with the standard analyzer; now I tried by myself and I found that this is NOT the behaviour of the standard analyzer. I will update my question. Thank you @AndreiStefan

Comment: I don't think there is anything you can do in the analyzer to affect this.  The [Exists query docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/query-dsl-exists-query.html) list a number of cases where, even though the analyzer emits no tokens at all, it is still counted as existing.  It appears that the exists query doesn't match only if the value for the field is null *before* analysis.